# vim: could I copy text from vim and paste it to shell prompt using only the keyboard?

Tags: vim, terminal, copy-paste

I am using vim 7.3 on the Ubuntu 12.04 terminal.

When editing a file in vim, I could select some text in visual mode and then use `"+y` to yank it into the system clipboard. I could then paste the text into ANOTHER Ubuntu terminal (using `shift-ctrl-v`).

However, if I could have access to only one Ubuntu terminal, I must temporarily leave vim by using `:shell` to go to the Ubuntu command prompt. After that I find that the yanked text no longer exists in the system clipboard and I could not paste it into the command prompt.

Is there any way that I could retain the yanked text in the system clipboard after using `:shell` (using keyboard only) ? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: "if I could have access to only one Ubuntu terminal" -- please explain how you made that happen

Comment: @jthill I am running a SSH terminal session and don't want to open multiple sessions.

Comment: That's what I thought.  You need to [set up your ssh connection to do X forwarding](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html), so the vim at the other end of your ssh connection knows there's an X server to talk to.  I've never had to set up sshd to do this myself, that link was just the likeliest looking hit.

Comment: Just use your Terminal's copy function, i.e. use mouse, vim copy won't help much in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround could be use a [terminal multiplexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) for your remote `ssh` sessions.

With `tmux` you can open more panes (or splits) on the same connection, you can work with `vim` in a pane (split) and the shell in the other.

With tmux you can copy text from a pane (split) to the other.
With the standard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> the workflow is this

1. In the `vim` pane enter tmux's copy mode mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
2. Highlight the text you want to copy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
3. When the selection is complete, copy the text to `tmux` clipboard with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>
4. Swith to the console pane in tmux (with two panes would be something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
5. Paste the text in the shell prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

You can see all the [tmux shortcuts](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tmux&sektion=1) by browsing the manual or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> while inside tmux.

There are some plugins like [tslime](https://github.com/kikijump/tslime.vim), [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux) and [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) that let you interact with a `tmux` session while in `vim`, like sending portions of text.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've just installed "tmux". It works and solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me with a gnome-terminal in Fedora and vim7.3.

- Select the text you want, for instance using visual mode.
- Press Ctrl-Shift-c
- Then enter ESC followed by :shell
- Once in the shell press Ctrl-Shift-v

If you also grab a newline when you copy it will execute as a shell command when you paste.

A side effect of this is that by doing :shell if you have vim configure to save .swp files, there will be one left in the current directory and the next time you edit the original file, you will need to deal with vim complaining about finding a swap file.

Comment: Not works in Ubuntu. Only works if the text is selected through the terminal, not through vim's visual mode. But I do not know how to select text through the terminal using only the keyboard.

Comment: You might search for GNU Screen, I have heard that it can select text with keyboard only, but I have no personal experience with it.